# Accessing annotations of attributes towards parent

Tags: java, reflection

Say I have two below classes

```
class Parent extends MyBase {
    @Annot(key="some.key", ref=Child.class)
    public List<Child> children = new List<Child>();
}

class Child extends MyBase {
    @Annot(key="another.key")
    public String id;
}
```

Now say I have

- a `Parent` class object => `parent` and
- containing 3 `Child` class objects in `children` list.

It means that `parent.children.get(0).id` can be accessed. 
Now i need to form the ***key sequences*** of the attribute **`id`**. 
Here `Key Sequence` is the concatenated string of all the `key` values of `@Annot` annotation.
For example, in this case the key sequence is **`some.key/another.key`**

Any way to get it done through java reflection?

Comment: what is key sequence? even with your example i can't really understand what it is

Comment: I couldnt find a better title for this problem. So anyone most welcome to give a better title.

Comment: sequence of the `key` value of `@Annot` annotation

Comment: do you expect to annotate only fields with it?

Comment: @hoaz: yes only fields will be annotated

Comment: Your question contains Custom annotation which is difficult to understand because logic behind custom annotation is unseen to us. Please be specific add your logic, expectation and actual result. so that community will think and try to answer that.

Comment: @Samiron Any way to get it done through java reflection? First tell what have you tried.

Comment: @RaisAlam: yes it is custom annotation and the specific logic you are asking about, im also looking for that.

Comment: @Sikorski: To be frank... i couldnt think of anything. thats why came here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way which doesn't use objects in `children`. It inspects generic type of children and scans this class to find an annotation.

```
    Field childrenField = Parent.class.getField("children");
    Annotation[] annotations = childrenField.getDeclaredAnnotations();

    String key = null;
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (annotation instanceof Annot) {
            Annot a = (Annot) annotation;
            key = a.key();
            break;
        }
    }

    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) childrenField.getGenericType();
    Class<?> c = (Class<?>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    annotations = c.getDeclaredField("id").getAnnotations();
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        if (annotation instanceof Annot) {
            Annot a = (Annot) annotation;
            key += "/" + a.key();
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(key);
```

See [this guide](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html) for more information about annotations.

Comment: Sounds promising... I need a bit time to assimilate your solution totally. I will get back with reply surely.